# How to export a function from a module as a class member

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to export a function from a module as a class property?

When class has a property which points to a function inside a module, that property acts like its **private** regardless of any modifiers (adding **public** doesnt do anything here)

For example, here are 3 ways to define property (a, b, c in example) that all do the same thing, but none give me what I'd like - which is to define function in some other module so class body does not grow out of control

```js
// myModule.ts
/** typedef this is a test */
export function func(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}

// myClass.ts
import * as myModule from './myModule';
export class MyClass {
  a(msg) { return myModule.func(msg); }
  b = (msg) => myModule.func(msg);
  c = myModule.func;
}

// index.ts
import { myClass } from './myClass';
const classInstance = new myClass();
classInstance.a('test'); // works but this way i cannot get typedefs from a module
classInstance.b('test'); // added just for completness, but its same problem as c
classInstance.c('test'); // works but tsc complains about property 'c' does not exist on type 'MyClass'
```

Comment: `c = myModule.func;` should work here. I copied your code into [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-volhard-6yblg?file=/src/index.ts) and it seems to work exactly like you expect. When I hover over `classInstance.c` I see the doc comment in the IDE just fine. I did have to fix the capitalization of `myClass` to `MyClass`, however, since `myClass` didn't exist in your posted code. Can you post a minimal reproducible example that shows the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the type in capitalization, otherwise this is exactly it - and your sandbox is exactly what I'd like to have. But in my env `classInstance.c()` works, but cannot get IntelliType for it and when I type it manually it shows a warning about property not existing - like its private. Maybe different TSC configuration? Btw, I'm using 4.4

Comment: You could try to make your `tsconfig.json` identical to the one from that sandbox and see if it behaves better, and then try to see what different settings you have that may be causing this. Also some IDE's cache type information and need to be rebooted occasionally to refresh the applications types fully. Or start a blank and completely empty project with this same setup and see if you have the problem there as well.

Comment: @AlexWayne I've added a lot more details below after digging at it - found the cause, but still have no idea how to solve it, it's not like i can use esnext just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started digging - issue is not when working fully inside TypeScript project,
issue is when compiling a TS module with class to a JS and then consuming that JS from anywhere else

compiled by TSC with `target=es2020`
TSC hides properties and they are only visible if typedefs are available
If typedefs are not available for any reason, properties `.b` and `.c` are reported as `does not exist on type MyClass`

Basically, TSC creates JS that is valid to execute, but is otherwise not really correct

> `myClass.js`

```js
export class MyClass {
  constructor() {
      Object.defineProperty(this, "b", {
          enumerable: true,
          configurable: true,
          writable: true,
          value: (msg) => myModule.func(msg)
      });
      Object.defineProperty(this, "c", {
          enumerable: true,
          configurable: true,
          writable: true,
          value: myModule.func
      });
  }
  a(msg) {
      return myModule.func(msg);
  }
}
```

> `myclass.d.ts`

```js
export declare class MyClass {
    a(msg: string): void;
    b: (msg: string) => void;
    c: typeof myModule.func;
}
```

When as compiled by TSC with target=es5 is ok ether way
as it doesn't rely on `Object.defineProperty`

> `myClass.js`

```js
var MyClass = (function () {
  function MyClass() {
      this.b = function (msg) { return myModule.func(msg); };
      this.c = myModule.func;
  }
  MyClass.prototype.a = function (msg) {
      return myModule.func(msg);
  };
  return MyClass;
}());
```

Guess what? With `target=esnext`, TSC generates perfectly fine code

> `myClass.js`

```js
import * as myModule from "./myModule";
export class MyClass {
    a(msg) {
        return myModule.func(msg);
    }
    b = (msg) => myModule.func(msg);
    c = myModule.func;
}
```

Basically, **ES5** doesnt have classes at all, **ES2018** does but defines each property using `Object.defineProperty` which is horrible. And **ESNext** is clean.